Templated constructor of abstract class without parameter type deduction in C++
I want my abstract base class to have a templated constructor, but can't get it to work without an extra parameter to deduct the type from.
I want to do something like this:
class Base {
public:
    template <typename T>
    Base() {
        /*Do something*/
    }
    
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base</*Some type*/>() {} // <-- Forbidden
    
    void foo () {}
};

I know that this does not work for non abstract classes because the syntax for constructing them would have the constructor template and a possible class template specification collide* with each other, but I can't see why it wouldn't work for abstract classes since you aren't able to instantiate them on their own.
*(For example with Base<int>() (assuming base is not abstract), it is not clear what the specified template is for. Class template or constructors function template.)
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Related/dupe: Is it possible to have a constructor template with no parameters? In particular, this answer: "There is no way to explicitly specify the template arguments when calling a constructor template, so they have to be deduced through argument deduction."

template <typename T> Base() is not a useable constructor.  You cannot call a constructor so there is no way to provide what T is.

The base class of the derived class shall be a template class, but you have defined a templated constructor (where the template shall be used for constructor arguments only).

@S.Gleissner on the other hand, templating the base class itself would make it more difficult, if not impossible, to have multiple derived classes with a common base class, depending on how they are used.

@NathanOliver Well this is the thing, I want to call it from the derived class and define T there to be used in the base class constructor you mentioned.

@S.Gleissner Remy Lebeau's answer to your comment is also the reason I have not use a class template. Also since I only need it in the constructor.

If you make the constructor take a T parameter, the derived class can pass one to the base. Derived() : Base(T{}) {}

@UniCode That's your issue.  You never call a constructor.  That's not a thing you can do. You either have to give the contructor a parameter of type T so it can be deduced when used or you make Base a class template.

@BoP: std::type_identity<T> is even better.

"I want my abstract base class to have a templated constructor" - I think this is where it got wrong. What's the ultimate purpose with this? Why is that important?

@TedLyngmo Well, I'm writing a behavior system for the ui elements in my (sort of) engine and I want to have each elements base initialized with the same default behaviors. I have a method initBehaviors() for that purpose which adds all the behaviors to a BehaviorManager object every ui element has. For adding I need to know the owner, as well as the parameters of every behavior. And this is where I need this for. I want the owner to always be of the derived type but simply don't know it in the base class + I want to always initialize default behaviors, so it should go in the constructor

@TedLyngmo I hope you understood at least a little, but it is important to note that this solution would not be the only one I see, but the only clean one for sure :).
I basically just want to be able to do Button(...) : UiElement<Button> {} (for example) in every ui element which is still kinda redundant but the cleanest I can think of at the moment.

what exactly is the question? Whats wrong with using a parameter to deduce the type?

@Jarod42 Unfortunately, std::type_identity is a transformation trait, which is not required to be constructible. Use std::in_place_type instead.

@UniCode I am glad you got an answer. For me it started to feel like an XY question.

@TedLyngmo Yeah I know what you mean but even apart from my use case I still would have liked to know if and how this might be possible or not. Just for a better understanding of C++ in general.

I suppose you do not want to pass the parameter of type T that would let you deduce T because the parameter would be unused. Otherwise you could just do that.
You can employ a tag whose only purpose is to transport the information on which T should be used and pass that as parameter:
template <typename T> struct tag{};
template <typename tag> struct T_from_tag;
template <typename T> struct T_from_tag<tag<T>> { using type = T;};
template <typename tag> using T_from_tag_t = typename T_from_tag<tag>::type;

class Base {
public:
    template <typename tag>
    Base(tag) {
        using T = T_from_tag_t<tag>;
    }
    
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base(tag<Derived>{}) {}
    
    void foo () {}
};

Live Demo
What you suggest wouldn't work for example when Base itself is a template. Base<T><U> just isn't C++ syntax. I suppose it would not be impossible to invent a language that would make what you want possible more directly, but in C++ that isn't required because there are other ways, for example using a tag as illustrated above.
PS: As pointed out by Raymond Chen C++17 introduced a standard template to achieve the same: std::in_place_type<T>:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {
    template <typename T>
    foo(std::in_place_type_t<T>) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int,T>) {
            std::cout << "T is int\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    foo{std::in_place_type<int>};  // prints 
    foo{std::in_place_type<double>};  // does not print
}

Live Demo

C++ comes with a built-in tag type for this purpose. in_place_type<T>. So you write template<typename T> Base(std::in_place_type_t<T>) { ... use T somhow ... } and invoke it as Base(std::in_place_type<Derived>) {}

Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. And even a standard library feature as @RaymondChen suggested. Thanks :).

And you are right. The parameter would remain unused if deduced just like that.

@RaymondChen your edit didnt compile https://godbolt.org/z/reWed3bhd

Sorry. Fixed. Forgot to delete the trail parens.

There is no use-case for what you are trying to do.
You would either move the template to the class itself or remove it since it can have no affect on construction unless you pass-in a value/instance/et. al. of T.
Using an imaginary syntax we could envision:
auto bi = <int>B();
auto bf = <float>B();
auto bs = <std::string>B();

However they would all invoke the exact same ctor so there's no point.
So there's no reason for it to be in the language even if we could add it.

Thanks for your answer but I certainly do have a use case for this. In the constructor I am invoking a templated member method to initialize my (as already stated in the comments below the question) behavior system with the default behaviors. Each of these need their owner type (the derived class) in order to be added which I have to provide inside the constructor. Hope it makes sense to you now :).

The constructor can very well do somehting different depending on a template parameter, and it can do so on a non-template class. https://godbolt.org/z/sv949rahz
